# How to Configure hotmail in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, hotmail

I have been trying to configure my hotmail account in Outlook 2007 and getting errors.I also tried Outlook connector but still unable to connect.It shows "Time: 7/1/2011 6:06:22 PM Error in Mail
This account does not have permission to synchronize your mail. To sign up to gain permission to synchronize with this account, please go to http://ideas.live.com and join the notification list for this Windows Live Hotmail product. You will be notified when your account is enabled.
Error: 3202. Server. HTTPS is turned on for the web but not for this program." error.
I also tried WindowsLive Mail 2011 but still same issue and shows "Unable to send or receive messages for the Hotmail (bhartiya.ravi) account.Server Error: 0x80048849
Server: 'http://mail.services.live.com/DeltaSync_v2.0.0/Sync.aspx'
Windows Live Mail Error ID: 0x80048849" error.
Please let me know any solutio.Thanks, Ravi

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Outlook 2007/2010 and Hotmail, you should download the [**Outlook Connector**](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/microsoft-office-outlook-hotmail-connector-overview-HA010222518.aspx) if you want REAL synchronization and not POP3.  It is part of the Live Essentials pack.

Comment: It also syncs the Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, you will have to enable IMAP or POP access to your mail. This would be on the mail website settings area where it would need to be enabled (This is at least the case with Google Mail).

To configure Hotmail with Outlook, check out http://www.nirmaltv.com/2009/03/27/how-to-configure-hotmail-pop3-access-in-outlook/